# Docker service creation taking more time

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, docker-swarm-mode

i'm new to this docker service creation please help me if i'm wrong , i executed this command
`docker service create --name "testApp" -p 8000:8000 testApp`
 Its taking too long time to execute (stuck at overall progress 0 out of 1 tasks) so that my shell is getting timeout .
anything wrong am i doing here??

Comment: Did you solve it?

Answer (score 1):

You can inspect the service task(s) to find out what's happening. The following command will show all the tasks for your `testApp` service.

```
docker service ps testApp
```

The `CURRENT STATE` and `ERROR` columns might give you some information. You can get the full status details by inspecting a specific task using `docker inspect $TASK_ID`, where `$TASK_ID` is the ID of the one of the tasks from the service. The `Status` section will show information like this.

```
"Status": {
    "Timestamp": "2018-07-28T10:45:03.4277984Z",
    "State": "running",
    "Message": "started",
    "ContainerStatus": {
        "ContainerID": "d85be58fc6f84e28ee42c578a65923237e3b60c1c82b18382c39d13a69b10b84",
        "PID": 40335,
        "ExitCode": 0
    },
    "PortStatus": {}
}
```

Usually, the information in there is enough to diagnose basic problems with creating a service.